# what's the difference between $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X]_n$ in terms of his roots?

Tags: polynomials

In terms of his roots, if $p$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}[X]=\{$polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $q\in \mathbb{Z}[X]_n=\{p\in\mathbb{Z}[X]/p=0$ or $deg(p)\le n\}$, both $p$ and $q$ has finite roots?

Comment: And what is gr(p)?

Comment: degree, i will edit

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking if a polynomial with integer coefficients has a finite number of roots...?

Comment: yes, but i can't find the difference between those sets i defined above

Comment: I suspect the confusion arises because you used $p$ to mean both a polynomial with integer coefficients and a prime modulus for the coefficients of the other polynomials $q\in \mathbb{Z}_n[X]$, apparently intending $n$ to limit the degree of the latter polynomials.  But this is a jumble, asking to compare apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that a polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$ can have any degree, while a polynomial in  $\mathbf Z_n[x]$ has degree at most $n$. Hence a general polynomial $p$ can have any number of roots ($<\deg p$, though), and a polynomial $p\in\mathbf Z_n[x] $ has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: i have to think that $n$ is fixed, right?

Comment: every polinomyal in both set has finite roots?

Comment: Yes, any polynomial $p$ with coefficients in a field has at most $\deg p$ roots. The same is true for coefficients in an integral domain.

Comment: so, basically are the same thing, in terms of his roots...

Comment: Absolutely. The main difference is that $\mathbf Z[x]$ is a ring, while $\mathbf Z_n[x]$ is not.

Comment: and if i defined $\mathbb{Z}_n[X]=\{p\in\mathbb{Z}[X]/p=0$ or $deg(p)= n\}$?

Comment: Do you mean: Is it a ring? The answer is no because the product of two polynomials of degree $n$ has degree $2n$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that over a commutative field you may have at most as many roots as the degree of the polynomial. $\Bbb Z$ is not a field, but is included in $\Bbb Q$, which is a field, so the roots over it must be finitely many, and the roots over $\Bbb Z$ are among them, hence finitely many.